# Any solutions on why I get a compile error with import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";

Tags: rust, anchor, solana

I've never seen this before. I try running anchor build and get a compile error of

```
1 | import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
  |        ^ expected one of `!` or `::`
```

I tried changing to '!' or '::' and get a syntax error so any solutions?

Comment: `@project-serum/anchor` is a JS library. Are you trying to import this in a Rust project?

Comment: Anchor project. but it's a .ts file. I also added 

// tsconfig.json

{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "allowJs": true,
    ...
  }
  ...
}

are you just not allowed to do this in typescript?

Answer (score -1):

To use libraries in rust, you need to first add it as a dependancy in your Cargo.toml file like so:

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.4"
```

Then you can use it in one of your rust files like so:

```
use rand;
```

It seems like the specific library you are wanting to import is a node package. You cannot use node packages in rust.
To view available packages for rust, check out https://crates.io/